# Android mediaPlayer only plays file once

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to create an app that play a certain audio file, that was previously recorded, when I press a button or shake my phone. Here is my code.

```
public class Reproduzir extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
SensorManager sensor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sensor= (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    setContentView(R.layout.reproduzir);
    Button reproduzir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reproduzir);
    reproduzir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            play();

        }
    });
    Button fechar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.fechar);
    fechar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
            }
            finish();


        }
    });

}
public void play(){
    try {
        player.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/2cp.3gp");
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    sensor.registerListener(this,sensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(event.values[0]>10.2
            ||event.values[1]>10.2
            ||event.values[2]>10.2){
        play();

    }
}
```

}

My problem is that when I run it, I can only play it once. If I press the button a second time or shake it again, it does nothing. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: in play() add `player.seekTo(0);` so it will always seek to zero and start playing track from start when you shake device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy fix is to simply add `player.reset()` in your `play()` method *BEFORE* calling `player.setDataSource(...)`.

You can only call `setDataSource(...)` once without resetting the player. It is legal to call `reset()` in any state however (even if the player isn't yet initialized).

In other words, even if it's the first time you've called `play()` it is OK to use the following code in your `play()` method...

```
try {
    player.reset();
    player.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/2cp.3gp");
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
}
// Your catch blocks here
```

Comment: Imo the best solution with a nice explanation. +1

Comment: This caused my media player to reset over and over again in an endless loop. I should note that I am doing my playback functions inside the `OnPrepared`  method within `VideoView.SetOnPreparedListener`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
mediaPlayer.reset()
```

after:

```
mediaPlayer.stop()
```

instead of release.

Comment: I only use release when the activity is stopped.

Answer (score -1):

You can only set data source once. 
in you code everytime the user presses the button you do this:

```
 player.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/2cp.3gp");
```

whice is wrong.

you need to setdata and prepare once and play how many times you want.

like so: 
put this in you onCreate:

```
try {
    player.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/2cp.3gp");
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
```

in the onClick(View v), just have :

```
player.play();
```

Comment: Do you have any source or reference to back this up and explain further?

Comment: There is no play() method on the MediaPlayer, or?

Answer (score -2):

Long story short - you have to use:

```
setLooping(true)
```

For more information about the Media Player check the post below. Take in mind the state diagram

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

[MediaPlayer State diagram](http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif)

Comment: **"you have to use: setLooping(true)"** : This wouldn't work - all that would do is force the sound to be played repeatedly in a loop. As soon as it finished, it would start again even if the `Button` wasn't clicked or the phone shaken.